# Checking in Safari if app is installed on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, installation

There's a lot of questions about that, and I can't find an useful answer.
It seems that Twitter already have a solution : when I go to mobile.twitter.com in Safari App, I can see a bar, a the top of the window with "Twitter Installed" and an "Open" link (i guess because the Twitter App is installed on my iPhone).

Is there because Twitter is "semi-integrated" with iOs 5 & iOs 6 (so they are more powerful than simple developers), or just because they are genius ?
If they are genius, do you know how they do it ?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're describing Apple's "Smart App Banners". Apple details how they work at [their developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html). Basically you add something like this to your web page:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

...and the device does the rest. If the app isn't installed, the button reads "install", otherwise it reads "open".